# Response testing for html tags in nodejs with express shouldjs or other assertion library

Tags: node.js, tdd, express, mocha.js

does anybody know of an extension of shouldjs or some other assertion library which helps to assert the response stream for html tags.

I would like to write some acceptance test like

```
body.should.contain.link 'login'
```

or

```
body.should.contain.h1 'Hello world'
```

Just an example that came up to my mind which could be pretty handy...

Or how do you guys test your response...?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chai Assertion Library has a plugin that you might be interested in, though that *exact* markup is not supported.

First off, if you're testing in the browser there is [chai-jquery](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-jquery). It would allow you to do things like this:

```
$('body').should.have('h1.title').text('Hello world');
```

From the looks of your snippet, you're testing on the server side, which makes things a bit more complicated. We had attempted to get chai-jquery working with node by using jsdom to parse the html returned from a server and loading it into a jquery object to test on, but jsdom doesn't play well with jQuery.

The alternative that I have seen (but have yet to try) is [cherio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio). It seems to behave more like jQuery is expected to. In which case, you could do something like this (untested)...

```
$('h1', body).text().should.contain('Hello universe');
```

Hope that is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem a few months ago but I can't seem to find the code. Heard a lot of people talk about [chai](http://chaijs.com) lately it has a api that is similar to should. Turns out it does have a [contain](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#include-section) method.